# Webcam extremely slow in Snap. How can I fix it?

Tags: usb, webcam, camera

I have a Logitech C270 USB Webcam. When I open Snap the webcam works but it goes really slow (low fps). My webcam is capable of recording video at 1280x720 @ 30Fps.

I've tried with `cheese` as well and I need to change the resolution to 800x600 or lower to get a decent fps. How can I fix this?

I'm using Loki stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you try to turn off the Automatic Light Correction the Logitech C270 uses.

Theres a tool for configure such stuff out for Logtich cameras on Ubuntu its called **guvcview**

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install guvcview`

To get into the control panel run
'guvcview -o'

There should be a point where you can turn out Automatic Light Correction.
Heres a thread about it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/361256/comments/10